The diagonal from Eigen LDLT is not in the same order as R chol()
I have a square, symmetric matrix, noted W, as input and I want to use a Cholesky decomposition (more specifically, the W = L D L' variant) to get two things: a vector of its diagonal values, and its determinant.
For this, I am using RcppEigen.
However, I cannot manage to have the diagonal elements in the same order in both R (with chol) and Eigen (with LDLT). Any idea?
Remarks:

LDLT uses pivoting, it's compulsory, and it avoids the square root on D, to be more robust and ensure stability.
For chol, pivoting is optional, and it uses the square root of D. Hence, in the R code below (at the end of the C++ file), I launches chol and I transform its input to avoid the square root. I also tried with or without pivoting, but in neither case do I manage to get the same order as LDLT.

Here is a minimal reproducible example with two files:

file 1 "manip.R"

library(Rcpp)
library(inline)
sourceCpp("det.cpp")


file 2 "det.cpp"

#include "Rcpp.h"
using namespace Rcpp;

//[[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]
#include <RcppEigen.h>
using Eigen::Map;
using Eigen::MatrixXd;
using Eigen::VectorXd;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double
mydet(const Map<MatrixXd>& W)
{
  Eigen::LDLT<MatrixXd> LDLT;
  LDLT.setZero();
  LDLT.compute(W);
  VectorXd vD = LDLT.vectorD();
  Rcout << vD << std::endl;
  double det = vD.array().prod();
  return(det);
}

/*** R
W <- matrix(nrow=5, ncol=5)
W[1,] <- c(5, 0, 0, 3, 0)
W[2,-1] <- c(3, 0, 0, 1)
W[3,-c(1:2)] <- c(4, 1, 1)
W[4,-c(1:3)] <- c(4, 0)
W[5,-c(1:4)] <- 2
W[lower.tri(W)] <- t(W)[lower.tri(W)]
W

base::det(W)

ret <- chol(W) # x = R' R, and ret = R
ret <- t(ret)
d <- diag(ret)
ret <- ret %*% diag(1/d, nrow=length(d))
diag(ret) <- d^2
diag(ret)

mydet(W)
*/

The R code returns this:
diag(ret)
[1] 5.000000 3.000000 4.000000 1.950000 1.384615

whereas the Eigen code returns that:
      5
      4
   1.95
      3
1.38462


The mathematical definition of LDL doesn't impose any order of the eigenvalues. So two different implementations have few chances to provide the same order. In the past, I was using my own programmes. For practical reasons, I was adding a further step to sort the values in decreasing order, modifyng the L matrix accordingly. If you do that in both cases, you will get the same order. Note that if two eigenvalues are equal, this doesn't guarantee that the L matrices will be equal.

Thanks, I see. But Eigen LDLT also starts with a permutation to reduce "fill-ins". From what I understand, it works roughly like this: (1) Eigen LDLT finds a permutation matrix P (so that PP'=Id) with some clever heuristics; (2) it permutes the input matrix: W* = P W P' and (3) it decomposes this permuted matrix: W* = L D L'. At the end, the input matrix is decomposed as: W = P' L D L' P. But it is not clear to me how to sort the eigenvalues while retaining the advantages of the permutations that reduces fill-ins.
